# Handlebars template - "tilde" in if statement

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, handlebars.js

We have statement like:

```
{{~#if someCondition ~}} 
<div class="whyweneedtildehere"></div> 
{{~/if~}}
```

What is the difference between simple `if` statement and `if` statement with "~" in handlebars templates?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is called a *tilde*, which might help you google it further.

The Handlebars docs [answers your question in detail](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#whitespace-control).

> Template whitespace may be omitted from either side of any mustache
> statement by adding a ~ character by the braces. When applied all
> whitespace on that side will be removed up to the first handlebars
> expression or non-whitespace character on that side.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, but it's not an answer to my question.

Comment: Did you check how your Handlebars is configured in your project, specifically? Did you grep for occurences of `{{~` and `~}}` other places than in your templates?

Comment: Upon further investigation, I found that it has to do with controlling whitespace. I’ve edited my answer above.

Comment: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#whitespace-control is the current link as of 2019.

Answer (score 12):

Here are some examples that might help you understand what `~` does.

**In `.js`:**

```
{
  hello: 'Hello, World!',
}
```

**Example #1:**

.hbs

```
<div>
  {{hello}}
</div>
```

.html

```
<div>
  Hello, World!
</div>
```

**Example #2:**

.hbs

```
<div>
  {{~hello}}
</div>
```

.html

```
<div>Hello, World!
</div>
```

**Example #3:**

.hbs

```
<div>
  {{~hello~}}
</div>
```

.html

```
<div>Hello, World!</div>
```

Basically, it's for removing whitespaces in the output HTML.